# ExtJS 4 unique records in few instances of store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have few instances of one store with memory proxy.

```
var store1 = Ext.create('app.store.SomeStore', {}),
    store2 = Ext.create('app.store.SomeStore', {}),
    record1 = Ext.create('app.model.SomeModel', {test: '111'}),
    record2 = Ext.create('app.model.SomeModel', {test: '222'}),
    record3 = Ext.create('app.model.SomeModel', {test: '333'});
```

How I can sync my stores to implement this functional:

```
store1.add(record1);
store1.add(record2);
store1.count(); //return 2
store2.add(record3);
store1.add(record3);
store1.count(); //return 2 becouse record3 already exists in store2
```

Comment: why you need this? why one store is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Find function checks if record with such value exists in the store

```
if (store1.find('test',record3.get('test') === -1){
 store1.add(record3);
}
```

extjs 3.4 [find](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-find) extjs 4.2.1 [find](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-find)